# Multithreading in Java-Android

Tags: java, multithreading

My problem is that I have an Activity and into there I want to take the result of the
read_list method. However the read_list method takes a lot of time to complete,
therefore I want to create a new Thread, and this to run this method and then 
return it to the main activity. I know that I can do smt similar with the
AsyncTask, however now I want to do it with this way.

```
  public class Read<T> implements Runnable(){

    Thread t;
    read(){
         t = new Thread(this);
         t.start();
    }


    public void run(){

       read_list();
    }


    public ArrayList<T> read_list(){

       ..........
       return ArrayList<T>
    }



 }
```

The main Activity:

```
 public Name extends Activity{

    .
    .
    .

    Read<Data> read = new Read<Data>();
    read.read_list();

 }
```

Question: With the aforementioned code, will I activate a new thread to execute the
read_list method? Or the method will be executed on the main Thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new thread won't be executed, however calling `read.read()` should start a new thread

btw. I would prefer using anonymous class, imho it is easier to read:

```
public Name<T> extends Activity{
  .
  .
  .
  private List<T> stuff;

  Runnable read = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      ...
      stuff = new ArrayList<T>(..);
    }
  };
  read.start();
}
```

Comment: or if your thread is only used for some computation and then it returns the data, you may use Future object for it (http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures), but I am not sure if it is in Adroid's SDK

Answer (score 1):

> Question: With the aforementioned code, will I activate a new thread to execute the read_list method? Or the method will be executed on the main Thread?

Only `Thread.start` starts a new thread and calls the object's `run` method in that new thread. So no, `read.read_list()` will not execute in different thread.

**BUT:**

```
read(){
     t = new Thread(this);
     t.start();
}
```

I assume that is supposed to be `Read`, it is the constructor. It too calls `start` and `run` calls `read_list` and discards the result.

So as is, `read_list` will be called twice, possibly *concurrently*.

Finally, I think you will have a hard time implementing `read_list`, creating and filling up objects of arbitrary types

Comment: Can you please propose me something in order to execute the method in a different thread and take the returned value of the method on the main activity?

Comment: The accepted answer shows this, but why do you want to use `Thread`? `AsyncTask`, `Future` are better